# Как задать размер двумерного вектора?

Tags: c++, строки, vector

итак, размер вектора будет N*m, я и хочу объявить его с таким размером (N и M) вводятся заранее

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    vector <vector <string>> pole(n(m)), pole2;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cin >> pole[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cin >> pole2[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cin >> n >> m;
vector <vector <string>> pole(n, vector <string>(m));
```

Т.е. `pole` - вектор из `n` векторов, каждый из которых - вектор из `m` строк...

Аналогично надо объявлять и `pole2`.